# Liferay java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.liferay.portlet.StrutsPortlet

Tags: java, tomcat, liferay, classnotfoundexception

I have an error which is already getting me crazy.

It's a Liferay 6.1 with Tomcat and we are talking about the preproduction environment. A portlet is deployed but it fails in the deployment phase. This is the error:

After this error, I see a message saying the portlet has been undeployed.

We have tried to deploy another .war which was working before but the error continues. This error only appears in the preproducction environtmet because in integration and production environtmets it is correctly working.

I have tried the next stepts:
- Stop server
- Delete temp folder
- Delete work
- Delete the portlet from webbapp
- Start server
- Check file permissions
- Check dependencies/libs with other struts portlet which is correctly working.

And nothing, as soon as the portlet is deployed (with a version that previously worked), the same error appears.

The portlet makes use of struts and I have also tried putting the library inside the portlet. But it is still the same.

Any idea?

This is the error:

```
17:37:58,240 INFO [localhost-startStop-2][HotDeployImpl:178] Deploying qui-es-qui-portlet from queue
17:37:58,241 INFO [localhost-startStop-2][PluginPackageUtil:1033] Reading plugin package for qui-es-qui-portlet
17:37:58,451 WARN [localhost-startStop-2][PortletLocalServiceImpl:1145] Duplicate struts path qui-es-qui
17:37:58,453 ERROR [localhost-startStop-2][PortletBagFactory:123] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.liferay.portlet.StrutsPortlet
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.liferay.portlet.StrutsPortlet
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletBagFactory.create(PortletBagFactory.java:120)
at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PortletHotDeployListener.initPortlet(PortletHotDeployListener.java:546)
at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PortletHotDeployListener.doInvokeDeploy(PortletHotDeployListener.java:321)
at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PortletHotDeployListener.invokeDeploy(PortletHotDeployListener.java:120)
at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.doFireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:188)
at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:96)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployUtil.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployUtil.java:27)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.fireDeployEvent(PluginContextListener.java:151)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.doPortalInit(PluginContextListener.java:141)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.portalInit(BasePortalLifecycle.java:42)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:64)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:56)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.registerPortalLifecycle(BasePortalLifecycle.java:52)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.contextInitialized(PluginContextListener.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1114)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1672)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site